# Python code reading data from CX Oracle resultset and shouldnot convert non english characters to string

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am reading the result set from `cx_Oracle` and converting it into json format using python.

So the problem I have is that there are some non-english characters which are converting into string and converting it to English characters (Example in my case 'Luís' to 'Luis'). Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Here is the code snippet which converts into json dictionary

```
def __execute_select(sql, cursor, **kwargs):

    cursor.execute(sql, **kwargs)
    columns = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set NLS_LANG to a character set that supports the characters you want retrieved. If that isn't the issue, provide the output from SQL*Plus and the equivalent output from Python as well as the various character sets in use.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I played with some `NLS_Lang` and I found this one `os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = ".AL32UTF8"` working for me and then I tried to decode with `utf-8` so it worked.